# Program doesn't work, add print statement it works, why?

Tags: c++

We have to write a gcd calculator, iteratively and recursively, and we are given a test script and my program fails 2/10 tests(`gcd_iterative(1000, 48) = 1000`, `gcd_iterative(48, 24) = 48`). so I showered my program with print statements 'and it worked. I started removing 1 statement at a time and there is 1 line where if I remove the statement it produces the wrong answer. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
using namespace std;

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int gcd_iterative(int m, int n)
{
    int r;
    while(r != 0)
    {
        r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
    return m;
}

int gcd_recursive(int m, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }
    else
    {
        return gcd_recursive(n, m % n);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <integer m> <integer n>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    istringstream iss;
    iss.str(argv[1]);
    int m;
    if (!(iss >> m))
    {
        cerr << "Error: The first argument is not a valid integer." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(argv[2]);
    int n;
    if (!(iss >> n))
    {
        cerr << "Error: The second argument is not a valid integer." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Iterative: gcd(" << m << ", " << n << ") = " << gcd_iterative(m, n) << endl;
    cout << "Recursive: gcd(" << m << ", " << n << ") = " << gcd_recursive(m, n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the print statement is `cout << "" << endl;`.

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? What input is not producing the proper output, and what output is it producing instead? If you want us to help you, you need to be specific and provide the details you already have (but we don't).

Comment: Have you checked that the output is correct yourself, or is this just based on the test script? If the script is looking for you to start on a new line, that could explain your problem. You haven't provided the implementation for either of the `gcd_*` functions, so we can't see what would be wrong with those.

Comment: @chirokidz I have check it without the test script and im debugging now

Comment: @KenWhite ./gcd 1000 48 produces Iterative: gcd(1000, 48) = 1000
Recursive: gcd(1000, 48) = 8
when there is no print statement, when there is it produces Iterative:gcd(1000, 48) = 8
Recursive: gcd(1000, 48) = 8

Comment: My bet is that the problem lies in `r` not being initialized in `gcd_iterative()`.  The initial value depends on previous stack contents.  That `cout` statement you have probably affects what is left on the stack for the next call, to `gcd_iterative()`.

Comment: I don't know how to debug in eclipse with c++, I'm sorry I'm very new.

Comment: I'm looking at this now, and this is a very strange bug.

Comment: I'll bet a dollar.  ;-)

Comment: @donjuedo changing to `r = 0` does not fix. Changing to `r = 1` does. You win, sir. Let me write up the full answer.

Comment: @donjuedo The default value of an integer is 0, and the loop condition -- immediately afterward loops on `while(r != 0)`, so this function always fails for any value where gcd(x, y) != x.  It succeeds with the cout, apparently because that causes the dead stack value to be nonzero.

Comment: Thanks @donjuedo and everyone else

Comment: @chirokidz, It makes sense that 0 would not work.  Any non-zero `r` to start the loop should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
int r;
while(r != 0)
{
    r = m % n;
    m = n;
    n = r;
}
return m;
```

The value of `r` is not initialized to anything, so if the initial value is zero, the algorithm will terminate on the while loop and just return the value of `m` unchanged.

C++ is not required to initialize the values of stack variables to any default value or anything else, so the value in the `r` variable is whatever was left on the stack by the previous function call. It would seem that it just so happens that `cout << endl;` leaves a nonzero value in the correct stack position for `r` to have a nonzero value, and actually run the algorithm. (Note that  if C++ did supply a default value, the default value would presumably be zero anyway, so you would still be forced to initialize).

In general, you should initialize the default values of stack variables to a safe value, rather than relying on their default values. So in this case, the fix is to set `r` to any nonzero value when you first declare it. E.g. `int r = 1;`

*Side note:* In C/C++ any integer value can be used as a boolean, and zero is false, so your while condition can be simplified to just `while(r)` rather than `while(r != 0)`; these are completely equivalent  expressions as far as the while loop is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

when program's result changes like this, it is likely you forgot to initalize some variable. In your case, it looks you forgot to initialize r:

```
int r;
while(r != 0)
```

'r' will get an arbitrary value (whatever happens to be in the CPU register). It is likely that without print statements, r is zero and thus the while() loop never runs. You want to set to non-zero value explicitly.

Comment: @chirokidz A new problem happened ./gcd 0 0 produces Floating point exception
same with ./gcd 1 0

Comment: Modulus (`%`) is a division operation (it returns the remainder after division). If the RHS is zero, the operation is a division by zero. You'll have to add a check if the right is zero before trying to do that, and handle it.